# Can i use Amazon Kinesis to connect to amazon redshift for data load in every couple of mins

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

From lots of sources i am planning to use Amazon kinesis to catch the stream and after certain level of data transformation i want to direct the stream to Redshift Cluster in some table schema. Here i am not sure as is it right way to do this or not ?

From the Kineis documentation i have found that they have direct connector to redshift. However i have also found that Redshift looks better if we take bulk upload as data ware house system needs indexing. So the recommendation was to store all stream to S3 and then COPY command to make bulk push on redshift . Could someone please add some more view ?

Answer (score 2):

When you use the connector library for Kinesis you will be pushing data into Redshift, both through S3 and in batch.

It is true that calling INSERT INTO Redshift is not efficient as you are sending all the data through a single leader node instead of using the parallel power for Redshift that you get when running COPY from S3.

Since Kinesis is designed to handle thousands of events per second, running a COPY every few seconds or minutes will already batch many thousands of records.

If you want to squeeze the juice from Kinesis and Redshift, you can calculate exactly how many shards you need, how many nodes in Redshift you need and how many temporary files in S3 you need to accumulate from Kinisis, before calling the COPY command to Redshift.

Comment: I saw the API code :  RedshiftBasicEmitter extends S3Emitter and so this means i have to put data from kinesis to s3 service and then s3 to Redshift cluster. Well that means i have to pay for S3 service also. I thought i can use Kinesis connector directly to Redshift without S3 in picture !!

Comment: You can always delete the files from S3 if you don't want to keep them. You can even do that automatically with life cycle  management policy

Comment: The reason for requiring s3 like this is that redshift is not where your data should live long term. It will cost more to host a redshift cluster 24/7 then leaving your data in s3 and booting up an emr cluster with hive when you actually need to run an analysis

Comment: @DanCiborowski Well, Redshift is whole a lot faster than Hive. Easily 10x-20x faster. Pinterest reported even 100x faster http://engineering.pinterest.com/post/75186894499/powering-interactive-data-analysis-by-redshift

Comment: Using RedStorm is fully supported/managed by Amazon, where spinning up an EMR with Hive is not entirely managed - is that so?

Comment: Did you mean Redshift? Elastic MapReduce (EMR) is also a managed service by Amazon, and Hive is installed by default (application=hive flag).